# Theoretical limit of upload file size

Tags: uploads

I want to setup a CMS on WP, which should contain a page, allowing to upload and download big files. We are expecting to use an Apache-server running on Ubuntu.

Assuming to adjust values, such as *upload_max_filesize*,

- which parameter limit the maximum file size
- what is the maximum possible file size (GB?)
- Are there other CMS, which allow to upload bigger files?

Comment: Hi and welcome to [wordpress.se]. "Theoretical limit": if we collect so many file servers that they form a star, that will in the end collapse under it's own weight and form a black hole. So maybe we are looking at the *Chandrasekhar* limit here ;-) Just kidding. I think general theoretical server questions might be better answered at StackOverflow, ServerFault or even at [physics.se] for very interesting answers ;-)

Comment: Recommendations are out of scope. About the maximum file size: Nearly every CMS will allow you to upload whatever your server is configured for. For the parameter see the question that I bind yours too now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Memory Limit depends on WP_MEMORY_LIMIT set by Wp_config file .So u can change the limit To higher value but Everything Depends on your Server Specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

Increase your `memory limit` in wp-config.php.

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

Increase the `maximum execution time` (max_execution_time) in your php.ini file. or in .htaccess php_value `max_execution_time`

Or I think go for drupal where good module available like [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot)

Comment: Please take your time and work on your format. Place code in codeblocks (`{}` on top of the editor) or backticks where appropriate. Thank you